# SAS Proc Means using Dichotomous Levels and PRT

Tags: sas, k-means

I am doing a lot of Mean Comparisons for assorted Levels

I do not understand why my p-levels would differ when I expect the test statistic to be the opposite for a case when I am working a case of two levels for my CLASS

```
Proc means data = prelim_notsnp2
  Mean prt;
  Vat q1–q24;
  Class CLUSTER;
Run;
```

Comment: Why?  What test is it that you think you are generating?  By adding a CLASS statement you have just split the data into multiple independent groups. Like a BY statement, but you didn't need to sort the data first.

Comment: Most of my CLASS tests are for 3 - 7 Levels and it would be both a decent and fun verification to test it when the number of levels = 2 - again holding everything constant, the test statistic for the two levels should be the polar opposite but with the same p-value

Comment: You are not testing CLUSTER. You are using CLUSTER to generate 3 to 7 tests for each of Q1 to Q24.

Comment: The code is not correct (would not run as posted) and proc means creates statistics. It can do tests, but the code you've shown wouldn't do any tests or generate p-values. The question needs more details about what it's trying to accomplish and what the issues.